# Python: memoization for the recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

Suppose we have the following recursion formula

[image]

I wrote the following code based on that recursion,

```
def f(k):
    if(k <= 2):
        return k
    elif(k % 2 ==0):
        return 5*f(k/2) + 1
    else:
        return f((k-1)/2) + 2
```

Is there a way to make this implementation faster and more efficient?

Comment: probably memoization (caching)

Comment: there are 2 thing you can do, one is use a memorization technique and the other is figure out a way to transform the recursion into a iteration

Comment: This is what you are looking for https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cache

Answer (score 1):

something like this

```
storage = dict()

def f(k):
    if(k <= 2):
        return k
    elif k in storage:
        return storage[k]
    elif(k % 2 ==0):
        storage[k] = 5*f(k/2) + 1
        return storage[k]
    else:
        storage[k] = f((k-1)/2) + 2
        return storage[k]
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use integer divisions because results will always be integers. Also, you don't need the parentheses around conditions.

There is a decorator in the functools module to automatically cache (memoize) your function:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f(k):
    if k <= 2:
        return k
    elif k % 2 == 0:
        return 5 * f(k//2) + 1
    else:
        return f((k-1)//2) + 2
```

*Note that this function converges extremely rapidly (exponentially?). The cache may not improve it much.*